# Sparql - return depth of recursion

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl

I have done a first query with recursion to search all child of a specific number :

```
SELECT distinct ?child
WHERE {
?child rdfs:subClassOf* num_108999. 
}
```

I would like add the depth of recursion , for example, if my data look like this :

```
108999 --> 2004 --> 218
```

I want in return:

```
?child | ?depth
_______|_______
2004   | 1
218    | 2
```

To make that I can use "UNION" and elt{n}:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
{
    SELECT distinct (1 as ?count) ?child
    WHERE {
    ?child rdfs:subClassOf{1} num_108999. 
    }
}UNION{
    SELECT distinct (2 as ?count) ?child
    WHERE {
    ?child rdfs:subClassOf{2} num_108999. 
    }
}
```

I think it's okay with 2 depth, but in complete data, I have 20 depth...
How can I pass the number of depth in auto-increment variable ?

Thank you !

Update : 
I found a little solution : split the occurence elt{ * } to elt{ + } and elt{ * }.

```
SELECT distinct (count(?mid) as ?count) ?child
WHERE {
?mid rdfs:subClassOf+ num_108999. 
?child rdfs:subClassOf* ?mid. 
}
```

It works fine with binary tree. But I haven't binary tree, my data looks like :

```
          /--> 2003 --\
108999 --/             \--> 218
         \---> 2004 --/
```

The previous query count each path : 108999 to 2003, 2003 to 218, 108999 to 2004 and 2004 to 218.

So the return value is 4 and not 2...

Answer (score 0):

First, note that

```
?child rdfs:subClassOf{1} num_108999.
```

isn't legal SPARQL.  SPARQL 1.1 didn't include the {m,n} specifiers for property paths, although it was in an earlier draft.  Virtuoso does support it, though.  The specification for it actually lets you do

```
  {n} # exactly n
 {m,} # at least m
 {,n} # no more than n
{m,n} # at least m and no more than n
```

That last form is exactly what you want (if you're using an endpoint that supports it):

```
?child rdfs:subClassOf{1,2} num_108999
```

That doesn't help you in finding the length of a particular path though, and you can't do that in SPARQL in general.  If there were only one path from the beginning to the end, then you could, but if there are multiple paths, you can't.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To make the union, the form {m,n} is great. But I would like to return the m or n in the result...

Comment: @Matthieu Yes, as I said in my answer, "[it] doesn't help you in finding the length of a particular path though, and you can't do that in SPARQL in general. If there were only one path from the beginning to the end, then you could, but if there are multiple paths, you can't."  SPARQL doesn't provide a way to distinguish between different paths between the same nodes.  The ?mid-counting technique works by counting how many nodes are reachable from a beginning and from which the end is reachable.  That only works when there's a single path, unfortunately.